# Wordpress: - Pull All attachment images including the Featured image

Tags: wordpress

I'm having real difficulty pulling all atttachments including the image... The thing is, I need to be able to control how the content is displayed...

e.g.

```
<a href="(Path-to-full-image)" rel="customrel" class="aclasstodeine">
<img src="thethumbnailsize(defined in functions.php)" alt=""
class="aclasstodefine" />
</a>
```

REALLY hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all attachment images you'll need to do a query.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'numberposts'    => -1
);

$images = get_posts($args);
```

This will load any image attached to the post into the $images variable then do a foreach loop on them to get your images:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $i) : ?>
    <a href="<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'full'); ?>" rel="customrel" class="aclasstodeine">
    <img src="<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>" alt="" class="aclasstodefine" />
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can read up on wp_get_attachment_image_src here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 0):

More likely it would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'numberposts'    => 1//-1
);
$images = get_posts($args);

foreach ($images as $i) :
    $poza_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'thumbnail');
    //$poza_fullsize = wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'full');
    //print_r($poza_thumb);//you will see that $poza_thumb is an array containing url, width, height
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $poza_thumb[0];?>" width="<?php echo $poza_thumb[1];?>" height="<?php echo $poza_thumb[2];?>" rel="customrel" class="aclasstodeine"/>

<?php
endforeach;
```